# copy pyqt table selection, including column and row headers

Tags: python, pyqt

I'd like to copy the selected part of a qt table, including the headers. The default qt table copy only copies one cell, whereas I need the entire selection, which can be multiple columns and multiple rows. I've spliced some code together from various places (mostly [here](http://retrofocus28.blogspot.jp/2013/09/pyqt-qtablewidget-copy-and-past-excel.html)), and it seems to work well except that it only copies the cells (data), not the headers. I need some help getting the headers for the selection as well. Here's my slimmed down sample:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(parent=self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setRowCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['col1','col2'])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['row1','row2'])
        self.table.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('foo'))
        self.table.setItem(0,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('bar'))
        self.table.setItem(1,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('baz'))
        self.table.setItem(1,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('qux'))

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.clip = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if (e.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            selected = self.table.selectedRanges()

            if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_C: #copy
                s = ""

                for r in xrange(selected[0].topRow(), selected[0].bottomRow()+1):
                    for c in xrange(selected[0].leftColumn(), selected[0].rightColumn()+1):
                        try:
                            s += str(self.table.item(r,c).text()) + "\t"
                        except AttributeError:
                            s += "\t"
                    s = s[:-1] + "\n" #eliminate last '\t'
                self.clip.setText(s)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Initialize the application
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWidget()
    mw.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The sample table looks like this:

```
     col1 col2
row1 foo  bar
row2 baz  qux
```

For example if I selected `bar` and `bux`, I'd like the copy to be:

```
\t col2\n
row1 \t bar\n
row2 \t qux\n
```

My actual case has a lot of columns and rows. My difficulty is in figuring out the headers for the selected cells; I can deal with the formatting. Any help or suggestions much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clicking on cells turns header items bold (by default), not 'select' them in the same sense. Clicking on header items also does not 'select' them (only the relevant row/column). Are you wanting the set of header/row items corresponding to the selected cells, or that the header items be directly selectable?

Comment: When I select a group of cells, I would like the copy to also include the headers, so that I know what data it is when I paste it. I'll edit to include an example of what I want.

Comment: Edited to include sample. Basically it boils down to I don't know how to get the headers for what's selected.

Comment: Note that, you can select individual cells with, for example, `ctrl+click`. So you can have a selection with `foo` and `qux` in it. What then? (Btw, your code doesn't account for those. You're only taking the first 'range', and you'll get two ranges for that case)

Comment: @Avaris, I had not considered that. For my purposes I won't be doing that but definitely would be something to take care of for production code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is in the header-items:

```
class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(parent=self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setRowCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['col1','col2'])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['row1','row2'])
        self.table.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('foo'))
        self.table.setItem(0,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('bar'))
        self.table.setItem(1,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('baz'))
        self.table.setItem(1,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('qux'))

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.clip = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if (e.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            selected = self.table.selectedRanges()

            if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_C: #copy
                s = '\t'+"\t".join([str(self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(i).text()) for i in xrange(selected[0].leftColumn(), selected[0].rightColumn()+1)])
                s = s + '\n'

                for r in xrange(selected[0].topRow(), selected[0].bottomRow()+1):
                    s += self.table.verticalHeaderItem(r).text() + '\t'
                    for c in xrange(selected[0].leftColumn(), selected[0].rightColumn()+1):
                        try:
                            s += str(self.table.item(r,c).text()) + "\t"
                        except AttributeError:
                            s += "\t"
                    s = s[:-1] + "\n" #eliminate last '\t'
                self.clip.setText(s)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had an issue with the .text() returning qstring and then not working with .join(), but converting it with str() made it work perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit older, but for people that are looking for a solution that allows them to select multiple ranges that are not necessarily connected, the following code works for me.

```
def copy_selection_to_clipboard(self) -> None:
    def intersects_with_ranges(ranges: list[tuple[int, int, int, int]], row: int, col: int) -> bool:
        # Checks if given row and col is in any given range
        for range_ in ranges:
            top, left, bottom, right = range_

            in_between_rows = row >= top and row <= bottom
            in_between_cols = col >= left and col <= right

            if in_between_rows and in_between_cols:
                return True

        return False

    model = self.model()
    ranges = [(r.topRow(), r.leftColumn(), r.bottomRow(), r.rightColumn()) for r in self.selectedRanges()]

    is_whole_table_selected = (
        len(ranges) == 1
        and ranges[0][0] == 0
        and ranges[0][1] == 0
        and ranges[0][2] == self.rowCount() - 1
        and ranges[0][3] == self.columnCount() - 1
    )

    row_start = min(ranges, key=lambda r: r[0])[0]
    col_start = min(ranges, key=lambda r: r[1])[1]
    row_end = max(ranges, key=lambda r: r[2])[2]
    col_end = max(ranges, key=lambda r: r[3])[3]

    rows = []
    for row_idx in range(row_start, row_end + 1):
        row = []
        for col_idx in range(col_start, col_end + 1):
            # empty value for not selected columns
            if not is_whole_table_selected and not intersects_with_ranges(ranges, row_idx, col_idx):
                value = ""
            else:
                # could also use EditRole if you have a customed model and want the raw value
                value = model.index(row_idx, col_idx).data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)

            row.append(value)
        rows.append(row)

    if is_whole_table_selected:
        rows.insert(0, [self.horizontalHeaderItem(i).text() for i in range(self.columnCount())])

    clipboard_text = "\r\n".join("\t".join(row) for row in rows)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().setText(clipboard_text)
```

Then just add an action to the table for `Ctrl + C`

```
action = self.addAction("Auswahl kopieren")
action.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"))
action.triggered.connect(self.copy_selection_to_clipboard)
```

(Code assumes that you inherited a `QTableWidget`)